# AFHTTPRequestOperation still running even the operation queue is suspended

Tags: nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, reachability, afnetworking-2

I'm using the latest AFNetworking V2.0. I have setup series of operations to be run on the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's operation queue if the reachability is available. I have setup a global AFHTTPRequestOperationManager in the appDelegate and uses that to check the reachability and when the reachability is not available i suspend the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's operation queue in order to avoid running the operations. When the reachability is back i make the isSuspended to false to restart the operations.

The problem i'm having now is even i have set the isSuspended to YES when the reachability is not available, the operation queue still fires and goes to the failure block of the operation.

This is my setup,

**AppDelegate.m**

```
self.reachManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:API_SERVER_URL]];
self.reachManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
__block NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = self.reachManager.operationQueue;
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

__block AppDelegate * weakSelf = self;

[self.reachManager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            NSLog(@"not reachable");
            [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
            [weakSelf showReachabilityAlert:YES];

            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            [weakSelf showReachabilityAlert:NO];
            [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            [weakSelf showReachabilityAlert:NO];
            [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
            break;
        default:
            [weakSelf showReachabilityAlert:NO];
            [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
            break;
    }
}];

[self.reachManager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

**View Controller**

```
AppDelegate *ad = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray * data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"media", @"analysis", nil];

for(NSString * c in data)
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:API_SERVER_SECTION_URL, c]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSLog(@"JSON: received for tag %@", c);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error message : %@", error);
    }];

    [mutableOperations addObject:op];
}

NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    NSLog(@"%d of %d complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");


}];

//Check the reachability and suspend the opearation queue if there is no reachability
if([ad.reachManager.reachabilityManager isReachable])
    [ad.reachManager.operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
else
    [ad.reachManager.operationQueue setSuspended:YES];

[ad.reachManager.operationQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:YES];
```

How can I suspend the operation queue when the internet is not there? and restart the queue when the internet is back?

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: I finally figure it out. This is not a AFNetworking issue. The problem was somehow the operation queue execution was started before the reachability block fired. I have edited my previous code with the final code if someone interested.

Comment: have u achieved this as i m still getting same error

Comment: Yes.. its working fine for me.. whats the error your getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited my previous code with the final code if someone interested.